# Can you check if a SignalR hub is online or not?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr

I have a remote hub that is running in a windows service that is connected to a TCP server. I want to be able to alert a user if the hub is online or not. I am using the following javascript code

Login Webpage:

```
<script src="Scripts/SignalR.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:1200/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

SignalR.js:

```
 try {
    $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:1200/signalr';
}
catch (ex) {
    alert(ex);
} 

srv = $.connection.tcpHub;

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    if (getCookie('UserID') != null) {
        Connect(getCookie('UserID'), getCookie('UniqueKey'));
        gotoState(availableState.READY);
    }
}).fail(function (reason) {
    alert("There was an issue connecting to Hub");
    console.log(reason);
});
```

None of the alerts are getting thrown because the webpage is breaking at the http script tag since the hub is not available.

Is there any way to alert to the end user that the hub is not online?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer my own question by changing

```
<script src="http://localhost:1200/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="http://localhost:1200/signalr/hubs" onerror="error();"></script>
```

and adding a error function to display the proper alert that the hub was not running.